# bootstrap collapse navbar not working. whenever i press the icon in a smaller screen the menu does not open, how do i fix?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, bootstrap-5

hamburger menu not working. whenever i press on the hamburger icon on a small screen the navigation does not appear. please show me how to fix this. :/

```
    <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="./index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="./images/StoreLogo.png" alt="Home" width="70px" height="auto"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
     <div id="navbarResponsive" class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
            </li>

        </ul> 
     </div>           
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Bootstrap 5, Some attributes are changed compared to bootstrap 4.
Change your code like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="./index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="./images/StoreLogo.png" alt="Home" width="70px" height="auto"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="./index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Click here for more Info [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#nav)